# How to validate custom dependent validation in fluent validation ? like validate the postal code for different countries

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, fluentvalidation

i want the validation like,
I have text box and i want to validate the postal code for the country where the site being open. like if i open the site in U.k then when i write postal code in textbox the textbox should validate only U.K postal code using fluent validation.i have try some code here but its not working.

in validator class file

```
public Ekhati_AdminUser_Mst_Validator()
        {
           RuleFor(x => x.Postcode).NotEmpty().Must(IsValidCountryCategory).WithMessage("Select a valid country");
        }

        public bool IsValidCountryCategory(Ekhati_AdminUser_Mst customer, string homeCountry)
        {
            homeCountry = "^(([0-9]{5})*-([0-9]{4}))|([0-9]{5})$";
            var ValidCountries = new List<string>();

            //categorias v�lidas para clientes do tipo R
            ValidCountries.Add("^([A-PR-UWYZ0-9][A-HK-Y0-9][AEHMNPRTVXY0-9]?[ABEHMNPRVWXY0-9]? {1,2}[0-9][ABD-HJLN-UW-Z]{2}|GIR 0AA)$");
            return ValidCountries.Contains(homeCountry);
        }
```

and in cshtml page

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.Postcode, String.Empty, new { @style = "color:red;!important" })
```

here i try this static entry only for testing.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you compare **input string** with **regexp value** and it's mistake: you shoul check if `Regex` object matches string. For validation by one regular expression you can use `Matches` rule:

```
public Ekhati_AdminUser_Mst_Validator()
{
    var homeCountry = "^(([0-9]{5})*-([0-9]{4}))|([0-9]{5})$";

    RuleFor(x => x.Postcode).NotEmpty().Matches(homeCountry).WithMessage("Select a valid country");
}
```

If you need to validate input string with more than one regexp — use `Must` rule, like in your example, but change validation method:

```
public Ekhati_AdminUser_Mst_Validator()
{
    RuleFor(x => x.Postcode).NotEmpty().Must(IsValidCountryCategory).WithMessage("Select a valid country");
}

public bool IsValidCountryCategory(Ekhati_AdminUser_Mst customer, string homeCountry)
{
    var validCountries = new List<Regex>();

    validCountries.Add(new Regex("^([A-PR-UWYZ0-9][A-HK-Y0-9][AEHMNPRTVXY0-9]?[ABEHMNPRVWXY0-9]? {1,2}[0-9][ABD-HJLN-UW-Z]{2}|GIR 0AA)$"));
    validCountries.Add(new Regex("...")); // another regexp

    var validity = true;
    foreach(var regexp in validCountries)
    {
        if (!regexp.IsMatch(homeCountry))
        {
            validity = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return validity;
}
```

Advantage of `Matches` rule is client-side validation support, but you can't use more than one match rule for one property.